# typescriptで配列内にアロー関数を書きたい

Tags: typescript

下記コードをtypescriptで書くにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

```
export default class Auth extends Vue {
public rules: { username: Array<string|boolean>, password: Array<string> } = {
// 以下の配列内でアロー関数を書いた際の型定義の書き方が分かりません。
// 現状だと型が宣言されてないとのことでエラーとなります
        username: [
            v => !!v || "ユーザー名は必須です",
            v => (v && v.length > 4) || "ユーザー名は5文字以上でなければなりません",
            v => /^[a-z0-9_]+$/.test(v) || "許可されていない文字が入力されています"
        ]
        password: [
            v => !!v || "パスワードは必須です",
            v => (v && v.length > 4) || "ユーザー名は5文字以上でなければなりません"
        ],
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

配列内に関数オブジェクトを格納させたい、という意味なら、2行目は

```js
public rules: { username: Array<Function>, password: Array<Function> } = {
```

または

```js
public rules: { username: Function[], password: Function[] } = {
```

と書くことができます。

関数の引数と戻り型も厳密にしたいならば、

```js
public rules: { username: ((v:string)=>string|boolean)[], password: ((v:string)=>string|boolean)[] } = {
```

のように書くこともできます。
（引数をstring、戻り値をstring|booleanにしたい、ということで合ってますよね？例えば引数がstring|booleanだと`/^[a-z0-9_]+$/.test(v)`の部分で型エラーが起きてしまいます）

Comment: 詳細なご回答ありがとうございます。
大変助かりました。
ご質問の、（引数をstring、戻り値をstring|booleanにしたい、ということで合ってますよね？
⇒その認識であってます